# What is happening in the response body of my http request?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I have a post request that when sent in python through the requests or aiohttp library, responds as expected, but when the equivalent request is sent in rust through the reqwest library, is pure gibberish.

The request:

```
pub async fn get_token(client: &reqwest::Client, uri: String, headers: HeaderMap, body: serde_json::json) {

  let user_name = env::var("USERNAME").unwrap();
  let password =env::var("PWD").unwrap();
  let resp = client.post(uri).headers(headers).json(body).send().await;
  if resp.is_ok() {
    println!("{}", resp.text().await.unwrap())
  }
```

Expected body of response:

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJ3aGhjaFFTRWF6Y2s1RmI5VyIsInJvbGVzIjp7Imdsb2JhbCI6WyJkcml2ZXIiXSwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbXX0sInNjb3BlIjpbImxvZ2luIl0sImlhdCI6MTY0ODYyNDkwOCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NjI4NTA4fQ.EQrLoG9cDQTXcbqBPZdfhN0cjOXRCeGz_cA8uTNF9kN4_rIVV4xcb67OwT8I03ch49V-BeA71qvbVDYdVqubNg5jxA6iSeTng-6aepGswyIaWYuDHx8KFUdaRWoZVh-WhIlDNSNIXkFbxnO4ggKy_Bf3nVJbIraWuitWWVcwjg8jbOy4cpjSkIjgiXUzMNL8_RWOIATvthplnw4MBsOpEsBsZkoYqfOjMmepojyGPE-FjrLYTWFZpB0PHV3OSv3mwZT-aAtI2yexZOSi6rz2TuBhPJVk93SfcXq-UeUPIlSrN7C6QI-6jVIzl9xFX1DKO0Uc8Fq3M-lvPnYkmY29G09h6Ltr9XPBRq9AZq-_r7yAH1lsWvWf1XhTwEOsFcACkH5Q5HxA4Ai50PegrHEhcBB9Cub9CPySMJ9oIewfj3cQURbRHAALbGXpiHBE7BU39QLUskuyzL4OGShaHliHQk1igyPRRHMdYeCGb1P39wB_Mq3nUzoH047QQ7KMGHb5azMPTLav7FsVmJhw7NOGIZtIyILz_07IcA_4XriokJuKUjBBOHuz82Ka7Vi6kthPsnDPplZ3i7TgQi8IptOWpm7IbhPAhTaSH5DuXFQfmtkWVNMcoVR6_Q8O1DNw9DVQmQwEycOA4SbbSYKmdVz0K8w81Kk7HGR6MGln4hEbrSk",
"refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJ3aGhjaFFTRWF6Y2s1RmI5VyIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlZnJlc2giXSwiaWF0IjoxNjQ4NjI0OTA4fQ.LDfwWeDPG11ZHNRo1Tks4LFY399VRKLI_cQnrxbGVAwlfCftOnIWw5-bsjXxMgnT6psL6D9EdKzBN8BNrw0eCis4U7EjVNUkGFegCmjPlO8gmdc_MRaHO-gN2TN43C-2jwbA9IojOw7UqVUtEzwp4px-OqnYNNIxqMnFOa5oe72v2ILJ5G3bD0J-0AQ-ly-Ce_lstDhObG-yVptIRcbt54OJ1Ou9PjPi9Y0OuVo6rwpQ1KKXdNc4GbQ_cOQKpQ6CJkDK-SjYByOFXC1pqD3aku4lxHpfx99K3RWFgmSeIN4VQLcQ7uBEWvBePEWUCEXSGiod1hK-gLAY0c-Io6NEygZWKIlACKoEphZLqyoKQ7vn-iMlN-8DGWX8Oh6gfT7ULhiG4U_JUheXxIzFvQBLfKtmXbKyagYEZ-y-Zl2nkAEZG2QzSm-cRAsTgquOvJvfujAtK3c5dHKoBL-0jIfnfWr4BHsptsWCc5J2SGtjjtTIG-Lh9d5mqgfN8TBVEK2R1JIeF0HxYPXcOO9CZZmqGqWp5YNZCJwppP2VJoVLSyzi3X5Cu0WWv7OpImmiR8H_M1JAn4XMyPMtyKFM5seewn8s6bOsZzELkKaPAFWbLlgeoJlDGA0CZtwFs2iJdd-UbS5C2dXUQw7yxVhRUIUq-pC1F3NVo51bRHgGzpcSYlE",
"token_type":"bearer",
"expires_in":3600}
```

The actual response:

```
�lMP�JX@z�ܦ}��>�}�CL>2�y@3%��`P�c:�L    �#D�t�
���X@*vk\p�\�*�Y�~u�f������J<����|}b    �M?^*&�d-u����2�!�hKU�1�`�dit�
�5W#�͛�Z1;F5��w�+��1.� DY#
���x?u]�äh(F��c�#���ů��Y{I�3XU�QN�+�pu�=��-X���+�5('�b9�бGz���l4��}����=Ȫ��FQm�����͂-��wiD� p�%S�>yq����d��/N�c2g���˛����kɋ%_�h5���9�]8�]���o�u�    � `u�~R�o7_9��S��C��%LPj^��#����}{B�� "�_}�IGb��p�:9Bۤ7�ٌT�_|cJDْ��Q�l��2@S��Rܣ\۳�}T�C+꽨ʹ�O����ƝW�����=�`th�忿��&dU��zh�I��X��_�1���oο��Vdp�������P�#���E�
ǣ��3�L��x�¡�?�~������Z��Bk���
(��$h`0�r���$wr��W꜄է��c
���7�0�E-�b��I6Q�ac���V�
��F��7���o�ݭ9�4��j<�a�/L��&dUZ��8����Åba!�X��.�������`ˣ�'A'���/sP,�m�?~v/�綔FR��|
]��l1�}\(]��̃�'㠊җ�)�
��EG2#�4�H�gd�x��p�������JՏ���+ϼ�m#��o=���)j=��\�}���pB<Tb×r��N���K�q��){+��u�HK�,Pu�+��絍m>D�=��$��|y�y��T/����F���
```

The issue is seems to obviously be some kind of format or encoding/decoding issue, but I can't find anything relevant to something like this. Anyone have an idea what the issue is?

**EDIT**

So I ended up being able to figure out what the issue was, and it was in the `Accept-Encoding` request header, whose value was `gzip, deflate, br`

I was trying to see if any of my configured request headers were the issue by just removing them one by one, and that header was certainly the issue.

The response headers now have the `Vary` header set to `Accept-Encoding`, so I'm not even sure what the actual compression mechanism is being used to produce the correct response.

Can anyone offer an explanation on why the `gzip, deflate, br` header when used in the python request would respond as expected while the rust request would not?

Comment: You just posted what looks like a valid JWT access token. I'm assuming it doesn't actually give access to anything, but in case it does, you may want to revoke it.

Comment: Aren't you suppesed to call the `send` method ? `client.post(uri).headers(headers).json(body).send().await`

Comment: Can you show us the response headers?

Comment: Maybe the answer is compressed? If so you can try enabling the `gzip` feature flag to `reqwest`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It was valid but only for an hour, so it's now long expired, plus I don't think there's anything revealing what the access token is for so I figured it was fine

Comment: @Peterrabbit Yes, `send` should've also been in the post (it's been in my actual code, I just missed it when copying it over). I've edited the post. Thanks for catching that